# Redim Preserve on loop cause an error of Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Im looping a folder and passing different elements to an array dynamically. When the array is empty and i `ReDim` it the array increase size but when the array has values and i try to `ReDim Preserve` i got an erro of:

> Subscript out of range

**Code:**

```
Dim arrNames As Variant

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

    'If array is empty
    If Counterarr = 0 Then
        'Add a line to the array
        ReDim arrNames(Counterarr, 1 To 3)
    Else
        'Keep the values and add new
        ReDim Preserve arrNames(Counterarr)
    End If

    'Import document name
    arrNames(Counterarr, 1) = Trim(Replace(Trim(StrFile), ".xlsx", ""))
    'Import Year
    arrNames(Counterarr, 2) = Trim(Left(Trim(Split(Trim(Replace(Trim(StrFile), ".xlsx", "")), " ")(1)), 4))
    'Import Month
    arrNames(Counterarr, 3) = Right(Trim(Split(Trim(Replace(Trim(StrFile), ".xlsx", "")), " ")(1)), 2)

    Counterarr = Counterarr + 1

    StrFile = Dir

Loop
```

**Image:**

When array initialized:

[image]

Any advice how to import `ArrNames(1)` etc?

Comment: Side note: Wouldn't you want to use `FileSystemObject` instead? That way you can use the [`Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) like `GetBaseName`, `GetExtensionName` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [ReDim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement):

> *If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array
>   dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all. For
>   example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that
>   dimension because it is the last and only dimension. However, if your
>   array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the
>   last dimension and still preserve the contents of the array.*

Means you cannot re-dimension the first dimension but only the last one

```
ReDim arrNames(FirstDim, SecondDim)
```

---

But instead of multi dimensional arrays you could use an array inside an array.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ArrayExample()
    Dim Arr() As Variant 'this is your outer array (container)

    Dim a As Long
    For a = 1 To 10
        ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To a) 'resize the outer array by +1

        ReDim OtherArr(1 To 3) As String 'this is a brand new inner array (each iteration)
        OtherArr(1) = "Item 1"
        OtherArr(2) = "Item 2"
        OtherArr(3) = "Item 2"

        Arr(a) = OtherArr 'here we write the inner array into the outer 
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]

And you can easily access it like `Debug.Print Arr(2)(3)`. Note that `Arr(2)` accesses the outer array and `Arr(2)(3)` accesses the array inside that array. This is different from a 2 dimensional array which would be accessed like `Arr(2,3)`.

Comment: suggetions how to restructure the array?

Comment: @Error1004 You can put an array into an arry instead of multi dimensional arrays. See my edit.

Comment: Nice, why `Dim OtherArr(1 To 3) As String` inside your loop though? It would simply overwrite each iteration, right?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, we need a new temporary array in each loop, in the end of each iteration we write it into the container array `Arr(a) = OtherArr`. Then `OtherArr` is not needed anymore and therfore we overwrite it in the next iteration. • Note these are actually 2 levels of one-dimensional arrays not a two-dimensional. See my last sentence in the edit.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, what I meant to say is that (when I test this), it makes zero difference if I would use `Dim OtherArr(1 To 3) As String` inside the iteration. I would therefor choose to keep it outside.

Comment: @JvdV Actually it is a good practice to declare a variable as close as possible to their first use. And secondly yes I was wrong, it must be a `ReDim` inside the loop to guarantee that the array gets emptied before using it (which we should!). See my edit. Now it makes a difference and it is necessary to have the `ReDim` inside the loop.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I always forget the strange behavior of VBA that `Dim` statements are like it was declared in the very beginning and not within the scope it actually is written. My fault.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for your answer. I will check it tomorrow and let you know the outcome. Lastly, how to check if the `Arr()` is empty?

Comment: @Error1004 You know that ^^, Stack Overflow is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290781/check-if-array-is-empty-vba-excel/26290860

Comment: @Error1004 Note that if you can determine how many files you will have, you can create the array in the correct size without using `Preserve` which makes it slow.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ got it. i ll be back for feedback!

Answer (score 0):

To add a new perspective:

I would avoid using `ReDim Preserve` inside a loop, especially if it is going to have a lot of iterations. See [this](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/redim-preserve.htm) or this [blog entry](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/proper-redim-preserve-syntax-and-best-practice.830139/).

A alternative solution could be to use a `Collection` instead. Here you can add Items to the Collection on the fly for example like this:

```vb
Dim fso As Object, oFile as Object
Dim my_coll as Collection

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set my_coll = New Collection

For Each oFile in fso.GetFolder(pathToFolder).Files
   Dim strArr(1 To 3) As String
   strArr(1) = Left(oFile.Name, Len(oFile.Name)-Len(".xslx"))
   ...
   my_coll.Add strArr
Next
```

You can then later iterate over the collection like so:

```vb
Dim it as Variant

For each it in my_coll
   Debug.Print it(1) 'Returns the Name
Next
```

You will have to enable the `Object Library` to use a `Collection`.